# \vdots missing in Fira Math?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, symbols

I use TeXLive 2020.
This simple code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\begin{document}

\[
A = \begin{pmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1p}\\ 
            a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2p}\\      
            \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 
            a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{np}
         \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Leads to this :

[image: Missing vertical dots]

Do you have any idea how I could tell XeTeX to "import those \vdots" from somewhere else ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Known issue https://github.com/firamath/firamath/issues/50

Comment: Off topic. In order to have nicer dots, you may be interested in the [`nicematrix` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé : very nice, indeed. Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the glyphs are missing in Fira Math.

You can use another sans serif math font.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range={\vdots,\ddots}]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[range=]

\begin{document}

\[
A = \begin{pmatrix}
            a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1p}\\ 
            a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2p}\\      
            \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 
            a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{np}
         \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not perfect, but passable for a presentation.

Comment: For my humble opinion it is the same font :-)..excellent!

Comment: @Sebastiano Well isn't it because it's still using Fira Sans? Tex Gyre is only used for vdots and ddots