# How can I use \vdots in the presence of unicode-math using lmodern or lmodern-like fonts?

Tags: unicode-math, lmodern

Consider the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\vdots}
\end{document}
```

Running this through lualatex gives

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
 L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))

No file a.aux.
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./a.aux))
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 484 words of node memory still in use:
   6 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 2 glue, 4 kern, 1 glyph, 6 attribute, 52 glue_spec
, 6 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:25,3:4,4:2,5:23,6:1,7:17,9:17
</usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on a.pdf (1 page, 2528 bytes).
Transcript written on a.log.
```

and a box with no characters in it.  [\vdots missing in Fira Math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540732/vdots-missing-in-fira-math) suggests that I want a different font, but I'm using the built-in LaTeX font here.  (My actual, non-minimal example, uses `\usepackage{lmodern}`, and gives the error `Missing character: There is no ⋮ (U+22EE) in font [lmmono12-regular]:!`)  What font should I use to get a passable vdots construction, or how can I redefine vdots to get my vertical dots back?

Comment: By the way, `\usepackage{lmodern}` is a legacy package for PDFTeX. You shouldn’t use it with `unicode-math`; Latin Modern is already the default.

Comment: By the way, If OpTeX (instead LaTeX) is used with source: `\fontfam[lmfonts] Test: \vdots \end` then the character `\vdots` is printed. LuaTeX prints the character from Unicode math font although not in math. mode. I don't know why LuaLaTeX does not work similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you’re in text mode, not math mode.  The font `lmmono12-regular` is your default `\ttfamily`.

Enter math mode inside your box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2

\begin{document}
\fbox{\(\vdots\)}
\end{document}
```

The `\tracinglostchars=2` line will give you a warning whenever a character is missing from the current font.

For the characters that really are missing from Latin Modern Math, such as `\setminus`, a good solution is `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}`, or `\usepackage[regular]{newcomputermodern}` for the classic lighter weight.  Both Latin Modern and New Computer Modern are based on Computer Modern (and the AMS fonts), but New Computer Modern Math is much more comprehensive.

Another fix that usually works for missing characters is something like

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} % For example
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[ range=\setminus,
                             Scale=MatchUppercase ]
```